# Django - Display User Email in User Profile Admin

Tags: django, email, admin

This may be a very simple question, but I haven't been able to find it in SO.

I created a User Profile Model for additional user info via OnetoOneField. Now for the Admin of the User Profile Model, I want to display the email field found in the User model. I tried:

```
# models.py
def email(self):
    return self.user.email

# admin.py 
fieldsets = [
    ('',    {'fields': [
        ...
        'email',
        ...
    ]})
]
list_display = (
    ...
    'email',
    ...
)
```

This worked for the `list_display` section, but for `fieldsets`, the following error popped up:

> Unknown field(s) (email) specified for UserProfile. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UserProfileAdmin.

Is there a way to work around this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets):

> `fields` can contain values defined in `readonly_fields` to be displayed
>   as read-only.
>
> If you add the name of a callable to `fields`, the same rule applies as
>   with the `fields` option: the callable must be listed in
>   `readonly_fields`.

So you need to add:

```
readonly_fields = ('email',)
```

to your model admin class, and then it will be available in the fieldset.

Comment: Thank you! This worked plus, it's good to know how readonly_fields can be done. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Put this

```
def email(self, obj):
    return obj.user.email
```

in your admin class of userprofile and you will be able to use it in fieldsets.